# sftp connection

Tags: php, joomla

When I' m trying to connect Sftp from my joomla site 
its not connecting:

```
    $c = ftp_connect('ftp.xyz.com')     or die("Can't connect");
    ftp_login($c, 'username' , 'pwd')     or die("Can't login");
```

in this case msg showing `Can't connect`

I also tried this code

```
  $connection = ssh2_connect('ftp.xyz.com', 22);
  if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
```

in this case no error msg showing

Please help me, if there is a proper solution help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed libssh & PECL ssh2 module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ftp_connect()` uses FTP, not SFTP. They're very different. So if your host is providing only SFTP, then no, that function won't work! SFTP is explained in more detail here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

`ssh2_connect()` is the right connection method to use, which is why it's probably working. You can see all the SSH2 functions available in PHP here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php

You'll probably be most interested in `ssh2_scp_recv()` and `ssh2_scp_send()` (for getting and sending files).